# typedef to alias of template template

Tags: c++, c++11, alias, typedef, template-templates

I got a traits class, AttributeTraits, that uses a smart-pointer template class, MySmartPointer :

```
template<typename T>
class MySmartPointer {};

template<template <typename> class SP = MySmartPointer>
struct AttributeTraits {
    template <typename T>
    using SmartPointerClass = SP<T>;
};
```

AttributeTraits use alias to hold the template class it have.
Now, I need that Attribute class that gets a trait class will use a typedef/alias to the smart pointer class, such:

```
template <typename Traits>
struct Attribute {
    typedef typename Traits::SmartPointerClass<int> SmartPointerType; // error: non-template 'SmartPointerClass' used as template
    using SmartPointerType2 = typename Traits::SmartPointerClass<int>; // error: expected ';' before '<' token
    using SmartPointerType3 = Traits::SmartPointerClass<int>; // error: non-template 'SmartPointerClass' used as template
};
```

But none of the 3 options above works...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of those times where your dependent class is a template, so you have to use the awkward `template` syntax when defining your alias:

```
template <typename Traits>
struct Attribute {
    typedef typename Traits::template SmartPointerClass<int> SmartPointerType;
    using SmartPointerType2 = typename Traits::template SmartPointerClass<int>; 
    using SmartPointerType3 = typename Traits::template SmartPointerClass<int>; 
};
```

See [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) for description of when you need the `template` keyword:

> **The `template` disambiguator for dependent names**
>   Similarly, in a
>   template definition, a dependent name that is not a member of the
>   current instantiation is not considered to be a template name unless
>   the disambiguation keyword `template` is used or unless it was already
>   established as a template name

[This StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) also provides some good background.